# scrollToElement in iScroll not working as expected

Tags: jquery, scrollto, iscroll, iscroll4

I am implementing two separate horizontal iScrolls which is related to each other using scrollToELement(). Whenever i select something from the first iScroll, I am using scrollToELement() to got the specific item inside the second iScroll by passing index value.

```
k_imageScroll.scrollToElement('li:nth-child('+index+')', 0)
```

It is working as expected - displaying the item to which i am jumping. 
But the problem is while scrolling the second iScroll, it starts scrolling from the first item. Even if i am jumping to middle item using  scrollToELement(), while swiping it starts from first item, not the very next item.

Please provide ideas to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.